# A lot of NPE of DeviceMotionService happen recently

Tags: android, webkit, android-webview

Recently my app on Google Play Store get a lot of NPE of DeviceMotionService. Following is the stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.webkit.DeviceMotionService$2.run(DeviceMotionService.java:103)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:1067)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I have no clue about this issue. I did use `WebView` in my app. But I checked source code. It seems a deep function in android framework/webkit.

Comment: Some people meet the same issue too. Paste another link here. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54877

Comment: I'm having the same issue too since a few days ago.

Comment: I have the same issue, interestingly all from the same device, PLT8802G (PLT8802G), and all running Android 4.2

Comment: Same here. No solution yet.